# Trying to open a Form by recieving a message from the server

Tags: c#, forms, sockets, user-interface

My target was to create a synchronized workspace for two clients (A GUI program that runs at both of them and synchronizing with text messages).
I have two buttons currently, the first one creates the socket with the server and the second one opens a new form (Form2 which is currently an empty form).
Clicking on button 2 will open the form for the current client and will send a message for the other client to open the form.
For some reason, the first form which is shown by clicking the button succeeds whereas the other client which is trying to be shown by the message from the first client does not succeed and is "not responding".
Why the form from the second client is not responding?
In both of the clients an instance of Form2 is defined before.
The code in both of the clients is the same code.
Code Samples:
1- Connect to the server by clicking button 1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 1 });
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
            Socket Server_Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                Server_Socket.Connect(remoteEP);
                Thread SendingThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CrazySendingThread));
                Thread RecievingThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CrazyReceivingThread));

                SendingThread.Start(Server_Socket); /*A thread that always sends the messages in 'msgtosend' list.*/
                RecievingThread.Start(Server_Socket);/* A thread that always try to receive a message from the server(if there isn't it waits).*/
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

2- Open a new form by clicking button 2:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {msgtosend.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("/OpenNP"));
            Np.Show();/* Np is defined as a global variable and built in Form1_load*/}
```

3- CrazyReceivingThread - the thread that always tries to receive:

```
public void CrazyReceivingThread(object srv)
    {
        string msg = "";

        Socket srvr = (Socket)srv;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
            int bytesRec = srvr.Receive(data);
            msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRec);
            string[] msg_array = msg.Split(' ');
            try {
                switch (msg_array[0])
                {
                    case "/Mouse_pos":
                        {/*is not relevant for the question...*/}break;

                    case "/OpenNP":
                        {
                                try
                                {
                                    Np.Show();
                                }
                                catch /*The form is 'Not responding' but this exception is **not** being caught.*/
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Form is not shown.");
                                }       
                        }
                        break;   
                }
            } catch(ArgumentNullException e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the code you are using?  Are you sure the message is getting through?  Are you sure the socket has been opened? Is the second client connected?

Comment: Code samplesadded. @pstrjds
Both of the clients are connected, I see the form in the second client but it is not responding so yeh, the message is getting through.
I also see the message in the server so the connection is OK..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your form is not responding is that you are trying to launch a `Form` in a background thread.  You will need to open the form from the UI thread (the thread that contains the message pump).  This is done by calling [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) (or `BeginInvoke`).  Since you don't list the main form code, I can't tell you an exact code replacement, but what you want to do is pass a reference to the main form into your thread method and in that method you want to invoke the `Form.Show` call:

```
case "/OpenNP":
{
    try
    {
        // where mainForm is a reference to the form
        // that contains the buttons, the main form that is shown
        mainForm.Invoke((Action)(() => Np.Show()));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Form is not shown. " + ex.ToString());
    }       
}
break;
```

Comment: https://gyazo.com/e5ab4cd18e840987755cd3f56bd06160
There are 3 syntax errors after writing this line.
I changed the 'mainForm' to 'Form1' which is the form that is shown in my project.

Comment: @OfirAizenberg - I made an update. I missed a set of parenthesis. My bad.